# Spinner options invisible until clicked

Tags: android, dynamic, spinner

I am trying to use a spinner to set the choices of another three spinners, which are updated dynamically using pre-defined string arrays in resources.

While I have used other excellent suggestions from stackoverflow to get this far, I am not sure why my 3 updated spinners show invisible choices until they are clicked on.

Here is the main code:

```
package com.example.bush;
import com.example.bush.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
public final static String NAME_KEY = "com.example.bush.NAME";
int pos1, pos2;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1, adp0,adp1;
Spinner spinner1,spinner2,spinner3,spinner4, spinner5;
EditText editText, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8;
int[] route1,route2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_h_route);
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_h1);
    spinner4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_h2);
    spinner5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_h3);
    num3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num_h1);
    num4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num_h2);
    num5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num_h3);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.route_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    Log.i("Hostile Route Spinner", "spinner1");
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Log.i("AAA", "OnItemSelected");
    pos1=spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
    Log.i("Spinner 1 Position", Integer.toString(pos1));
    switch(pos1)
        {
        case 0:
            adp0 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.first_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adp0.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            spinner3.setAdapter(adp0);spinner4.setAdapter(adp0);spinner5.setAdapter(adp0);
            break;
        case 1:
            adp1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.second_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
            spinner3.setAdapter(adp1);spinner4.setAdapter(adp1);spinner5.setAdapter(adp1);
            break;
        }
    }

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}

}
```

Here is the .xml table layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrolltest.xml"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_label"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label1"
                android:width="0px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_name"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:width="0px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/edit_message" >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_h_route"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/label2"
                android:width="0px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_h_route"
                android:width="0px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/route_array" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_h1"
                android:width="0px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/num_h1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:width="0px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_h2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:width="0px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/num_h2"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:width="0px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_h3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:width="0px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/num_h3"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:width="0px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here are the String resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Bush Calc</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">Bush Calc</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Hi there :)</string>
    <string name="unit_prompt">Choose a unit</string>
    <string name="route_hint">Choose the route.</string>
    <string name="label1">Your name:</string>
    <string name="label2">Attacking route:</string>

    <string-array name="first_array">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <item>Item 2</item>
        <item>Item 3</item>
        <item>Item 4</item>
        <item>Item 5</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="second_array">
        <item>Item 6</item>
        <item>Item 7</item>
        <item>Item 8</item>
        <item>Item 9</item>
        <item>Item 10</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="route_array">
        <item>First</item>
        <item>Second</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Thanks for any help you can offer to make these options visible on the spinner!

Answer (score 1):

This is the way, you can set adapter for spinner, try this

```
 Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, R.array.route_array));
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Using the "createFromResource" line requires 3 inputs rather than 2, so unfortunately this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the use of the incorrect adapter resource.

```
adp0.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
```

should be

```
adp0.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Do this like you did when setting `adapter1` at the beginning.

Change all your `...item_1line`. layouts to the one provided.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issues with other drop menu, spinner, etc. I think there's several ways around this, but I think the easiest is to define/create a theme in the manifest. I have used your code, and it works.

For example, in the manifest I added:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.invisablespinner.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
      => " android:theme="@style/Simple" >
```

In the style xml inside layout\values\style.xml. I added.

```
<style name="Simple">
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item> <== make the text black
     <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item> </style>
```

Define background color or it'll be whether you textcolor will be...as far as what I have seen through my test of the code.

There's a lot of ways to adjust it to make it look nice. It's all up to you.

~Ann :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution!!!

in the styles.xml

```
<style name="Simple" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
     <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item> </style>
```

the  in the manifiest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Rescate"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_rescate"
    android:theme="@style/Simple" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some time ago a very similar problem where the default style of the device were very stupid set. So that the forceground and backgrould color where equal. So you need to set the background and forceground color by hand.

Comment: The strange thing is that I use the same style of spinner for all of my spinners. The first spinner operates fine and as expected, but the dynamicly changing spinners do not, even though they use the same style. Do you know how I would go about changing the background and foreground colous by hand if this was the problem however?